# PouchDB JS File being served as CouchDB Attachment Isn't Properly Loaded

Tags: javascript, html, couchdb, pouchdb

I've made an application with a PouchDB frontend that is stored as a CouchDB attachment.

I have this html page stored at localhost:5984/repository/b/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="/repository/b/pouchdb.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>practice</title>
    <div id="practice">
    </div>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="app"></div>

      <script src="/repository/b/build.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/repository/b/store.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pouchdb.min.js is successfully stored at the src referenced in the head.  I try to reference it in store.js:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/repository');
var text;
var b = document.getElementById('practice');
db.info().then(function(info) {
    text=info;
}).then(function(){
    b.innerHTML=text;
});
```

I get the error

```
ReferenceError: PouchDB is not defined
```

When I look in my debugger, in the application section of chrome, it shows that the pouchdb file contents are loaded.  In the network section, all of my resources are showing 304 errors.

Can anyone guess what might be going on here?

Comment: Do you have permission to create/access the "repository" database on your CouchDb server? Can you (for example) get database info for it using a CURL command? I ask as you are not supplying a username/password in the code.

Comment: I'm curious, how are you serving your HTML? Are you using NodeJS/ExpressJS? Or something else?